# Company Registration in Android Market

Tags: android, google-play

Sorry, the question is not programming related but I have nowhere else to ask, I asked in android help center and support without any responses.

What do I need to open a company account in Android Market? I want my company to be seen as seller. How will they authenticate the company, what documents do I need to supply to the market?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a Google Checkout account

Answer (score 4):

Ok, so here is the official answer I got from the Android Team :

> Thanks for writing in. At the moment,
>   we only support merchants in certain
>   locations, and we're working hard to
>   add more. If you are legally able to
>   do business in one of the supported
>   countries and otherwise satisfy the
>   Google Checkout terms of service for
>   that country, you may register as a
>   merchant for that country. Please
>   check here for the most up-to-date
>   list of supported merchant locations:
>   http://market.android.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=150324

Answer (score 0):

If you sign up as a developer, you get the option to add your business details by signing up for a checkout account afterward.

Note that I think this is the only way to get a checkout account outside the US and UK... I tried to get a checkout account before but couldnt get one :S (Australia)